# Css z-index not working in safari and webkit

Tags: css, webkit, z-index

I have a page that displays a span and an image, the idea is that the span appears above the image so that the image appears behind the transparent parts of the text: http://www.luckysaddleupholstery.com.

The webpage is fairly simple:

```
<body>
<div id="content" >
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="pages">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="/page/LUCKY_SADDLE/">LUCKY SADDLE</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="/page/designs/">designs</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="/page/info/">info</a></li>
            <li >
                <a href="/page/contact/">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    <ul id="subpages">
    </ul>

        <div id="layoutItem40" class="layoutItem textItem titleText" style="left: 0px; top: 196px; width: 556px;"><span style="font-size: 42px; line-height: 42px; color: #B84C59;">VINTAGE. MODERN. TRADITIONAL. BY HAND. STUFFING. HIERLOOM. nostalgic. shabby. recycle. textiles. worn. forgotten. spring. unique. restore. </span>
        </div>
        <img id="logo" src="/static/img/logo.png"/>
        <div id="contact"><strong>T</strong> 07961 706 522<br /><span><strong>E</strong> <a href="mailto:ruth@luckysaddleupholstery.com">ruth@luckysaddleupholstery.com</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bodyWrapper" style="top: 14px; position: absolute;">
    <div id="body" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="layoutItem49" class="layoutItem imageItem" style="left: 288px; top: 0px; width: 748px;">
            <img  src='/static/media/imgs/Richard-Moore-Chair-Main.jpg' />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The relevant parts of the css:

```
.layoutItem {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.textItem span {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.imageItem img { 
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
#nav {
  width: 172px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 1px;
```

}

There is more css that effects the elements and their parents but this is all text styling, rather than positioning.

The concept is that the large text in the nav column overlays the body div - which contains the image, allowing the image to be scrolled underneath.

The image and text are rendered from a CMS system which is why the html is slightly convoluted, although very customisable!

The renders fine in Firefox, but recently seems to have become broken in recent versions of Safari / Webkit.

Comment: Can you show the CSS for the parent elements?

Comment: Giving `.imageItem img` a negative `z-index` will work, but the image will then be unclickable if that matters.

Comment: cheers Adrift -1 for the z-index of the img does work! Still don't understand why, but thanks again!

Comment: The image doesn't have to be clickable, because I can surround the image in an <a> tag.